# How to use webfsd

Tags: webserver

I have install webfsd on my computer which OS is Ubuntu 14.04,Can anyone teach me how to use it like editing configuration files?Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/webfsd.1.html .

This is the man page and often a good place to start. Try using google to get further information on any extra questions you may have. If you need information from askubuntu, try to come up with a more narrow question.

Comment: thank you very much,it's my first time to ask question online ,thanks anyway